# reactjs manifest settings to specific url

Tags: reactjs, manifest.json

I'm working in my very first ReactJS application.

I've set start_url in manifest.json  as follows-

```
"start_url": "http://localhost/myapp
```

But the app still loads at "http://localhost.
How can I load the app from "http://localhost/myapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `basename` attribute in `BrowserRouter` solved my issue-

```
export default function App() {
   return (       
       <BrowserRouter basename="/myapp">
          .......    
       </BrowserRouter >         
    ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The manifest.json file is just a [web app manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) this doesn't change how the local web server runs.

Why do you want to change the address during development? It's not a very common requirement.

Running the webserver from a different sub-folder on a remote server is quite common but is a bit of a different question.